# What does accept rate mean?

Tags: support, terminology

I sometimes see thigs like "68% accept rate". What does this mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tooltip reads:

[image]

So I guess it speaks for itself.

For more information: [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)